# Monotouch: insert an UISegmentedControl into UIPopoverController header

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I would insert a UISegmentedControl into UIPopoverController header. How can I do?
Check this link.
[UISegmentedControl embedded in a UINavigationBar/Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417673/uisegmentedcontrol-embedded-in-a-uinavigationbar-item).
I would replicate a similar behavior.

Thank you!!

**EDIT: In particular, the UISegmentedControl is composed by three segments. Each segment displays a different views inside the UiPopoverController.**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the link you posted yourself. Embed your view controller in a navigation controller and add the segmented control as the title view of your navigation item. The popover controller is smart enough to recognize this and will draw your navigation bar as part of its own header.