# UISegmentedControl in a PopoverController with multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to have a UISegmentedControl embedded in a PopoverController, similar to what is described in this SO question : [UISegmentedControl embedded in a UINavigationBar/Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417673/uisegmentedcontrol-embedded-in-a-uinavigationbar-item)

The difference is that I have a different view controller for each view that I want to show in the popover, depending on the selected index on the Segmented Control.  I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.  Whenever I try to push a new view on top of the root view controller, the UISegmentedControl disappears.  I would just like to switch between the two viewcontrollers, while keeping the UISegmentedControl visible.  Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a different viewController for each one of the segments on the segmentBar, you'll have to use a container viewController that adds the views of each of the viewController as a subview on itself or sets its view to that of the viewController's view.  For example:

```
UIViewController* containerController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];


//Inside the viewDidLoad of the the ContainerController class, do the following:

//Initialize all three viewControllers
UIViewController* test1 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewController* test1 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewController* test1 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

//set up the segment and add it to the container's navBar's title view.
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


- (void)segmentValueChanged:(id)sender 
{

    //if first tab selected
    [self.view removeAllSubviews];
    [self.view addSubview:test1.view];

    //if second tab selected
    [self.view removeAllSubviews];
    [self.view addSubview:test2.view];

    //if third tab selected
    [self.view removeAllSubviews];
    [self.view addSubview:test3.view];

}
```

Instead of adding it as a subView, you might be able to just set `self.view = test1.view`.  Obviously, you would use the container view to initialize the navController and put that navController inside the popover.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, @Bittu, this is actually what I ended up doing.  Just wanted to see if there was a more elegant way of doing this.  Guess not.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `presentModalViewController` method to show your new view controller on the screen, it will always cover the entire screen and what ever is underneath it. That's just how it works.

As per docs:

> On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of modalViewController is
>   always presented full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the
>   value in the modalPresentationStyle property.

The way to do it and still being able to control how the view controller is positioned is to create your own presentation method.

Comment: First, thank you for you're input.  But I'm afraid I dont understand what you mean.  I am presenting a UIPopoverController, so I am using the function presentPopoverFromRect: inView: permittedArrowDirections: animated:  I pass my UINavigationController (which contains my custom view controller) in as the content VC of the popover.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I dont think presentModalViewController can apply here